Mac OS issue when accessing website with nodejs running on port 8080
I have a very odd issue that recently started happening. When accessing a website with NodeJS service running on port 8080, it will not connect to the service and keep showing an ERR TIMEOUT in the web console.  I have tested with other devices on my network (Windows PC / Mobile / Tablet) and they all work fine connecting to the website w/NodeJS service so I know it's not my network/router...there's something on my Mac that's causing this.
Couple weeks ago I tried learning to develop in flutter language and installed the SDK with Visual Studio Code, I am thinking that has something todo with a web emulator running on port 8080 or has changed something in my system settings that's causing this.
I tried deleting flutter completely but I'm sure something is still lingering because it continues to happen.
UPDATE I also had Android Studio and Docker installed which I removed completely and still have the issue...
Only when I'm on the website and I do a port scan in terminal I see this:
user@MACSN ~ % sudo lsof -n -P | grep :8080
webfilter  2362                  root   18u     IPv4 0x9ef469fd6bf55a1b        0t0                 TCP 192.168.106.98:59260->192.168.0.49:8080 (ESTABLISHED)

I tried to look up the PID (2362) in Activity Monitor but it doesn't show up...

Does anyone know if the android/flutter web emulators use port 8080 and possibly causing this? If so how can I get this resolved?
Any help/feedback is appreciated.

Thanks for the downvote.  I come here as a last resort from troubleshooting for weeks trying to figure this out myself.  Atleast provide a comment for downvoting so I can improve my questions...

This sounds like you are saying: everything else connects to a server at :8080, except my macOS. So the most likely problem is that your macOS is doing name resolution incorrectly... If you aren't using a URL with an IP address, you should try that... (use dig to find the IP address for the hostname/fqdn in the URL... then connect to that...)

@benc I don't think its DNS because I can access the site but just not the nodejs service on port 8080 (using the same URL as the website), when the nodejs service is switched to port 8081 it works on my mac but that was just for a test as it has to stay on port 8080...  I'm close to doing a wipe reset on my mac ... so frustrating.

Thx for the info. If all the browsers and web utilities on your Mac cannot connect to server:8080, then you should still try for an outbound packet trace on the Mac, an inbound packet trace on the server, and the connection log on the server (although with a timeout, there will often simply be no log entry).
If you have 3rd system that is basic proxy server, configure a browser and connect thru it. Whether it works or fails, it cuts the problem "in half".

I did some packet tests and could not get anything logged with a timeout as you said.  I forgot to mention that this is a work computer ... I reached out to a colleague that also has a Mac and he has the same issue so I know that it's not just my mac, I believe there was a company mac profile change that was pushed out and is blocking port 8080.   I'll reach out to the bozo that made this change and get it sorted...  Thank you and really appreciate all your time and support on this.

Good luck with that conversation... people have pretty narrow views of what a port actually is...
